# C# Have an issue in update method with particuler rows using TableAdaptor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tableadapter

I am trying to make a form which display all the information of a user(firstname, lastname, email..) in textboxes. And then there is a button which the user can edit the fields and submit the update to the database through TableAdaptor and Update method.

The problem is that I want to update particular columns not all the columns.
btw I am using `visible = false` to force the user not to edit a particular field.

This is my server side i am using.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Session["Login"].ToString();
    string Password = tbOldPassword.Text;
    string newpassword = tbNewPassword.Text;
    string Firstname = tbFirstname.Text;
    string Lastname = tbLastname.Text;
    string Email = tbEmail.Text;
    DateTime DOB = DateTime.Parse(tbDOB.Text);
    string Mobile = tbMobile.Text;
    int Gender = int.Parse(tbGender.Text);
    int Country = int.Parse(tbCountry.Text);


    MembersTableAdapter mta = new MembersTableAdapter();



    // no overload for method 'Update' takes 5 arguments

    mta.Update(Firstname, Lastname, Email, DOB, Mobile);
    lblMessage.Text = "User profile has been updated !";


}
```

I am biggener and I want to learn from you.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you viewed what parameters your update method needs? intellisense should be able to tell you what you need. Also, this might be of some use to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233819(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I guess it needs more than 5 arguments. but my question is how can i update some and keep the others.

Comment: take a look at the link i sent to you. it says that you need to pass a datatable, datarow, dataset.... so what does your method require??

Comment: It works when I put it like this mta.Update(Password, Firstname, Lastname, Email, DOB, Mobile, Gender, Country, username); But I can't update the other columns. I am supposed to grant the user to update only these five columns.

Comment: why not create a stored procedure that you can call that only takes the parameters that you require?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21739/discussion-between-7alhashmi-and-ric)